# Is there a good solution for syncing photos between the Photos app and Amazon Cloud Drive?

Tags: photos, data-synchronization, icloud

Amazon Cloud Drive offers great pricing: Unlimited storage for $50 a year. Bundled with Amazon Cloud Drive (and with Amazon Prime) is a service that lets you make online photo albums, etc., which can be viewed online via via a web browser.

What I'd like to be able to do, and haven't yet found out a way, is to synchronize my photos in Apple's Photos app with the online photo albums that come bundled with Amazon Cloud Drive / Amazon Prime.

I already know about Arq, which is a great backup tool that works with ACD. I.e., it turns ACD into a CrashPlan-like backup service. What Arq doesn't do is backup your photos in a way that Amazon knows to display them as photo albums online.

I already know about PicBackMan. I would have thought that this program would do the job, since it seems to support nearly every cloud service known to Man. Unfortunately, Amazon Cloud Drive is not one of the services that it supports.

I know that I can drag and drop photos from the Photos App onto the Desktop and then into the Amazon Cloud Drive app, and then use the Amazon Drive web page to make photo albums. That's way too much work. I want something that's automatic.

Thanks.